# Woocommerce - How to add additional fee based on selected radio option?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a few **radio options** to my **checkout page**.

When a user selects a radio option, I want to **automatically refresh the page and add a fee** to the checkout page based on what was selected.

For example:

> If you select "Option 1" it will add a fee of $10.

> If you select "Option 2" it will add a fee of $20 etc.

Here's my code in the **functions.php** file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','calculate_extra_deliveryoptions' );

function calculate_extra_deliveryoptions() {

   echo "<form action=\"\"><br/>";
   echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"deliveryextras\" id=\"option1\" value=\"10\">Option 1 <br/>";
   echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"deliveryextras\" id=\"option2\" value=\"20\">Option 2 <br/>";
   echo "</form>";
    
   WC()->cart->add_fee(__('A small fee', 'option'), 5);
    
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the selected value, refresh the page and add the fee.

Comment: [WooCommerce: Add Checkout Fees Based on Custom Radio Button](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-checkout-fees-based-on-radio-button-choice-ajax/)

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it displays the options but when I click on it, it doesn’t refresh the page?

Comment: It is done via an ajax call, why would the **entire page** have to be refreshed?

Comment: I meant that the Ajax call didn’t refresh. I copied the code and pasted into functions.php. Not sure if I have to do anything else on the client side for Ajax?

Comment: I have not written that code but I can confirm that it works without more

Comment: Ok good to know. I’ll try again and see if something is blocking the Ajax call